# Ignore Arithmetic Overflow in microsoft sql server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm doing some bit manipulations in SQLServer. And have encountered the famous "Arithmetic Overflow" error. The case is, I want it to overflow. How can I tell it to allow overflow and ignore the error?

I'm doing this select:

```
SELECT CONVERT(bigint, 0x8000000000000000)-1
```

I want this to return 9223372036854775807 (the biggest bigint), but it returns:

```
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type bigint.
```

Comment: I don't know what your needs are, but you're trying to convert the value 0x8000000000000000 to a bigint. That value exceeds the maximum value of what a bigint can be (as you know). But that's why you are getting the overflow.   FYI: This works: SELECT CONVERT(bigint, 0x7fffffffffffffff)

Answer (score 4):

How about this:

```
SET ARITHABORT OFF;
SET ARITHIGNORE ON;
SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF;

SELECT ISNULL(CONVERT(bigint, 0x8000000000000000)-1, 9223372036854775807)
```

See MSDN references on [ARITHIGNORE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184341.aspx) and [ARITHABORT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190306.aspx)

Comment: Yeah, I know this is older, but it did the trick for me.  A query in an application was failing because of one bad column in one row.  In my situation, it's better to have that come back as NULL.  Thank you @AdaTheDev!

Answer (score 0):

That *specific* expression fails because the -1 is an int & so you need to;

```
select CONVERT(bigint, 0x8000000000000000)-CONVERT(bigint, -1)
-9223372036854775807
```

but that's neither the minimum (because of the -1) or maximum; if you want the +ve maximum;

```
select CONVERT(bigint, 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)
9223372036854775807
```