# ARITHABORT, ARITHIGNORE - do I need to turn them back on?

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, error-handling, azure-sql-database

This might be fundamentally stupid, but here goes:

I have a stored procedure that I need to just run without throwing overflow errors. In case of an overflow, I'm happy with a NULL.

I see it suggested all around the internet (eg. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8971534/ignore-arithmetic-overflow-in-microsoft-sql-server/8971785#8971785) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7097171/sql-safely-downcast-bigint-to-int/7101243#7101243)) to just use

```
SET ARITHABORT OFF;
SET ARITHIGNORE ON;
```

That is fine, but should I, like, turn them back on at the end of my SP?

```
SET ARITHABORT ON;
SET ARITHIGNORE OFF;
```

Like this? Are these even the defaults?

Also, Do I need both switches to get it to ignore overflow errors (in my case, trying to put '606006000' in a SMALLINT field)?

Using Azure DB v12.

Comment: Shouldn't need to. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190306.aspx indicates ARITHABORT should always be set to  ON on Logon session, "You should always set ARITHABORT to ON in your logon sessions." implying that its session specific. better clarifications: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190356.aspx  Note it impacts the SESSION so as long as you're releasing the session before next query and getting a new session, it will be reset automatically

Comment: @xQbert Thank you, the second site is a good read. Post this as an answer an I'll accept it.

Comment: @xQbert Yep, from your 2nd link: "If a SET statement is run in a stored procedure or trigger, the value of the SET option is restored after control is returned from the stored procedure or trigger." Thank you, my google-fu was weak today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some info about these settings.By Default both are true.

**SET ARITHIGNORE:**
The SET ARITHIGNORE setting only controls whether an error message is returned. SQL Server returns a NULL in a calculation involving an overflow or divide-by-zero error, regardless of this setting

**SET ARITHABORT:**
The SET ARITHABORT setting can be used to determine whether the query is terminated

Further this is what [MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189118(v=sql.105).aspx) has to say about these more..

> This setting does not affect errors occurring during INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE statements.
>   If either SET ARITHABORT or SET ARITHIGNORE is OFF and SET ANSI_WARNINGS is ON, SQL Server still returns an error message when encountering divide-by-zero or overflow errors.

I did some testings and it seems <kbd>SET ARITHIGNORE OFF</kbd> setting is only enough for the behaviour you need..

Further you also need to set <kbd>SET_ANSI_WARNINGS_OFF</kbd> as well ,other wise this will throw error

```
SET ARITHABORT OFF
--SET ARITHIGNORE OFF
SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF

select 1/0

declare @a tinyint
set @a=10000
select @a
```

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation. This explains why I couldn't get it to work in the end - I needed ANSI_WARNINGS too.